# What does (int -> int) mean?

Tags: sml

I'm trying to decipher the meaning of the type choice part of this. From what I can gather, it's multiplying an `int`, by `(int -> int)`, by another `int`. I'm just confused as to what `(int -> int)` means. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
val callcc = SMLofNJ.Cont.callcc
val throw  = SMLofNJ.Cont.throw
type 'a cont = 'a SMLofNJ.Cont.cont

type choice = int cont * (int -> int) * int
```

Answer (score 1):

( int -> int ) means a function that takes 1 int argument and returns an int. What you are defining is not a multiplication. 'choice' is a type defined as a 3-tuple. The 3-tuple consist of an int, a function that takes an int and returns an int, and finally another int.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by clarifying some things that I think you've misunderstood:

- `type choice = ...` is declaring `choice` as a "type constructor", meaning that it denotes a *type* rather than a *value*. The right-hand-side is then a "type expression"; for example, you could write `type myInt = int` to declare `myInt` as an alternative name for the `int` type.
- `int * int`, in a type expression, doesn't mean "an int times an int"; rather, it denotes the type "pair of `int`-s". For example, the value expression `(1, 2)` has type `int * int`.

That out of the way . . . `int -> int` denotes the type "function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`". For example, the value expression `fn i => 2 * i`, which is a function that takes an integer and returns double that integer, has type `int -> int`.

Putting this together,

```
type choice = int cont * (int -> int) * int
```

declares `choice` to mean "a triple (3-tuple) whose first element is an `int cont`; whose second element is a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`; and whose third element is an `int`".